# CSS Font declaration using Percentages and Fractions?

Tags: css

```
body {
    font: 90%/1.6 baskerville, palatino, 'palatino linotype', georgia,serif;
}
```

I'm trying to grasp the concept of what "90%/1.6" is doing in this declaration. I understand that the 90% is requesting to show 90% of the viewport, but not sure how the 1.6 is affecting this and why it's needed.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: 90% is the font size and 1.6 is the line height.

Comment: For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font#Syntax

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

As @DarrenKopp commented:

> **font: 90%/1.6**

*is shorthand for:*

> **font-size: 90%**
>   **line-height: 1.6**

Which means that:

> The font-size is 90% of that of the parent element of ‘body’ (i.e. the ‘html’ element).
>
> The line-height is this font-size multiplied by 1.6

**Documentation and further explanation**

This is documented in the [CSS 2.1 Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/css2.pdf), section 15.8, Shorthand font property:

```
[ [ <'font-style'> || <'font-variant'> || <'font-weight'>]? **<'font-size'>** [ **/ <'line-height'>**]? <'font-family'>] | caption | icon | menu | message-box | small-caption | status-bar | inherit
```

The most pertinent example in that section is:

> p { font: normal small-caps 120%/120% fantasy }

which explains *font-size*:

> …the 'font-size' (120% of the parent's font), the 'line-height' (120%
>   times the font size…)

Consulting the section on *line-height* reveals that this can be expressed as:

```
normal | <number>| <length> | <percentage> | inherit
```

And explains *number* as:

> The used value of the property is this number multiplied by the
>   element's font size

Comment: As this question had not been formally answered I have fleshed out the comment made by Darren Kopp into an answer. I make no apology for doing so. The Stack Overflow model requires formal answers, and this question, although old, is still pertinent in my opinion.